# Calculating VaR from copula-GARCH using rmgarch

Tags: r, time-series, garch, quantiles

I'm new to both R and copula, nevertheless I want to compare VaR estimations for 25 days ahead using a GARCH and a copula-GARCH model in R.

To calculate VaR for the GARCH model seems pretty straight forward, however, for the copula-GARCH I am a bit uncertain and would like someone to disapprove or confirm my hypothetical method.

The plan is to calculate VaR by simulating $N$ samples for 1-day ahead estimations using `cgarchsim` in the `rmgarch` package for the copula-GARCH. I'm using a CCC model so the correlation matrix (for two time series) is constant. Given

$\text{VaR}_t \approx \sigma_{t}F^{-1}(\alpha)$

I want to estimate the inverse, $F^{-1}(.)$, at time $t$ by using the quantile function on my $N$ simulated samples. By using the estimated returns to be the starting values for the next 1-day ahead simulation, I want to repeat the process 25 times.

The VaR is calculated for the returns, so even though the correlation matrix is constant, the variance for each simulated residuals could work as the variance at time $t$, ($\sigma^2_t$), or possibly use the correlated portfolio variance, $w\Sigma w^T$ where $w$ is the weight for asset $i$ and $\Sigma$ is the correlation matrix.

What I am hoping to get help with is

1. Can VaR be calculated for the copula-GARCH this way?
2. Should the variance be constant using $w\Sigma w^T$ or estimated with each simulation?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think I may have answered the question in one of these threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula+garch+user%3A53690

Comment: Thank you. After reading through the post I found that this one explains simulations quite well https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/571783/forecasting-using-copula-garch-methods/572056#572056 and this one explains time dependent variance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578812/obtain-minimum-variance-hedge-ratio-from-a-copula-garch-model/578858#578858, and what I took away was if I want time dependent variance then I should change the model.

Comment: @RichardHardy However I do have to push for another question. I’m trying to find a comprehendible solution due to the fact that I don’t understand the theory behind the R implementations that well. After calculating VaR for the $N$ simulations I am going to have to use 1 out of $N$ simulated returns as starting values to get the 2-day ahead simulation. Given the returns ($r_t$) and the standardized residuals ($z_t$), could I not just calculate the variance using $\sigma_t = r_t/z_t$ for each time series and use those values to get a new covariance matrix?

Comment: That's a good question. I have not found the time to sit down and think about it carefully. However, it is true that $r_t=\Sigma_t^{1/2}z_t$, so if you have $r_t$ and $z_t$, I think you should be able to obtain $\Sigma_t$ by pure algebra.